# InfluxDB Query on 'disk' measurement taking forever

Tags: influxdb

In InfluxDB 0.10.0, a Kapacitor TICKscript that I am using is timing out. So to remove Kapacitor from the picture, I am trying to do this simple query from the machine where InfluxDB is running:

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "db=telegraf_UP" --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM disk LIMIT 5'
```

The query is taking 3 minutes to return. But if I do the exact same query on the 'cpu' or 'mem' measurements, it returns fairly quickly (3 seconds for 'mem', 30 seconds for 'cpu'). All of those measurements should have the same amount of data, since they were all turned on in Telegraf at the same time.

Any ideas why such a big difference in the response times?

Comment: I see why it's taking so long - it writes out a measurement for every filesystem on the server, and there are 11 filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

In Influx 0.10 and earlier, the LIMIT clause limits the return, not the points sampled. If there are 10 million points in that measurement, it will pull all 10 million off disk and then throw away all but 5.

Starting with the new query engine in InfluxDB 0.11 the LIMIT clause applies to the points sampled and so the query will return in a similar time across measurements with wildly disparate point counts.